# Isolation test rails best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a Rails application. Saying it's a Rails app that allow you to nurse some animals and we have an action to give some food to many animals in same time. To do that we have a class that iterate on each animal and call the `#eat` method. The `eat` method is a transition from the state `starved` to `sated`. This transition fails if the animal is already `sated`.

Example:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  state_machine :state do
    state :starved
    state :sated

    event :eat do
      transition starved: :sated
    end
  end
end

class EatingService
  attr_reader :error_models, :models

  def new(models)
    @error_models = []
    @models       = models
  end

  def process
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      models.each { |model| @error_models << model unless model.eat }
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless successfully_completed?
    end

    successfully_completed?
  end

  def successfully_completed?
    error_models.empty?
  end
end
```

Before adding the transaction, I could test it easily with mock objects.

Now, I know that I shouldn't use my `Dog` or `Cat` class because the `EatingService` class is not tied to any classes but how can I test that the rollback works well on a dummy objects?

PS: In this example, I only talk about `Animal` but in the real application I have totally different type of classes using the "`EatingService`", not only animals or these inherited classes.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion such design breaks OOP principle "Tell, Don't ask" so it's hard to isolate the test.

Eating service takes too much responsibilities which don't belong to them. Starving or not is not this class should care. All the service need to do is to ask the animal to eat. As to eat or not, that's the business of animal.

I suggest logic like below, moving the judgement to Animal.

```
# Eating service
def process
  food = prepare_food
  @animal.eat(food)
end

# Animal
def eat(food)
  return false unless is_hungry? || like?(food) 
  chew(foo)
end
```

All animal needs to do is to respond to the method `eat`, which can be easily mocked. And the Serice's job ends with sending animal to eat.

Comment: The eating service doesn't know if the animal is starved or not. It just each over the objects and call the `eat` method. The object `animal` is the only one responsible to fail or not. I just have to rollback all the previous actions if at least one `eat` call does not complete successfully.

Comment: The eating service is a **generic** service it is not tied to a specific type of objects (Animal or children) but is used with totally different type of objects too. So when I write the tests to this service I don't want to tied this service to a specific class (saying animal). But, if I use a mock object, I can't test the ActiveRecord::Rollback :/

Answer (score 0):

Comment out all your code. Then write a test that files because one of your lines is not there. Repeat until you have code. Don't cheat and write the code first.

And your tests should use whatever objects they need. "Isolation" does not mean a test on a target class A is incapable of finding bugs in class B. Test isolation just means a test passing or failing depends on the fewest factors possible, including other tests, and including other target classes.

And try not to use mocks. I have seen projects slowed down despite having >1,000 test cases, because the tests abused mocks and often neglected to test the actual code.

Comment: The term "isolation" in this place was just use to say: "How to test a **generic** service working on any `ActiveRecord::Base` object that responds to a certain method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check that `ActiveRecord::Rollback` was thrown:

```
it "fails if someone is sated" do
  allow(ActiveRecord::Base).to receive(:transaction).and_yield
  allow(subject.models[1]).to receive(:eat).and_return(false)

  expect { subject.process }.to raise_error ActiveRecord::Rollback
end
```

Comment: Yes but a test shouldn't test the behavior instead of the implementation ? My test was just:  subject.process;  expect(models.map(&:state)).to eql(['starved', 'starved', 'sated'])  But I think I can't do that. I think your solution is the best compromise :(